# Incremental build is not working for gradle multiproject

Tags: android, gradle

we are using multiproject structure like this.

-app

settings.gradle

build.gradle

-----libraries:commonLib

-------build.gradle

-----libraries:lib1

------build.gradle

-----libraries:lib2

---

We have total 6 library projects.
a. app depends on all libs.

b. lib1, lib2, etc all depends on commonLib.

now we are facing two problems.
1. Incremental build is not working. Always we have to run
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
2. For our mid 2010 macbook pro its taking 40-45 minutes to build.
So what can we do fast build and any idea why incremental build is not working?

Comment: Well, maybe if it's so time consuming to build a dependency library/project You should consider installing this lib as a maven dependency and add appropriate entry in dependencies {} block?

Comment: `gradle build --info` will tell you why a particular task isn't up-to-date. `gradle clean` of course forces a full rebuild.